# Relations between Gödel's theorems

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I think, this is connected to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295452/g%C3%B6del-completeness-theorem), but I am not sure.

I am reading books on mathematical logic, and I face various difficulties in understanding details related to Gödel's theorems. I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following.

Joseph Shoenfield in his [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568811357) gives the following formulation of the Gödel completeness theorem:

> *A theory T is consistent iff it has a model.*

I think I don't understand something, but for me this looks like a statement that, in particular, the Peano arithmetic must be consistent, since it has a model as well. On the other hand, the second Gödel incompleteness theorem [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Second_incompleteness_theorem) the following:

> *Assume T is a consistent formalized system which contains elementary    arithmetic. Then the statement that T is consistent is not deducible inside T.*

I would think that this means impossibility to prove the consistency of Peano's arithmetic (within the predicate logic), since

> Suppose we "proved the consistency of PA in some theory $T$". Then a question immediately arises if $T$ itself is consistent, because if $T$ is inconsistent, then each statement (i.e. each formula) $A$ in $T$ is deducible in $T$ together with its negation $\neg A$. In particular, the statement "PA is consistent" is deducible together with the statement "PA is inconsistent". So we come to a situation where for proving what we want we have to continue our work, and prove that the theory $T$ is consistent as well. But by the second Gödel theorem, this is impossible inside $T$, and we have to find another theory $T_1$, and so on. And the question remains open at each step.

And for me, as an outlooker (I am a specialist in analysis, not in logic), this contradicts to the previous statement that PA is consistent.

What do I miss here? How is this "contradiction" settled? If in the Gödel completeness theorem people mean the relative consistency, why isn't this  stated explicitly?

**EDIT.** To people who vote to close this question: could you, please, explain your motives?

Comment: "this means that it is impossible to prove the consistency of Peano's arithmetic." NO: this means that the formal system of first-order PA cannot prove its own consitency.

Comment: "Peano arithmetic must be consistent, since it has a model ". Intuitively, YES: the "usual" natural numbers are a model of PA. But a formal proof of it requires the "maufacturing" of a structure and a formal proof that this structure satisfies Peano's axioms. This can be done in some formal tehoery: e.g. ZF set theory.

Comment: In the second Gödel theorem the theory T not necessarily coincides with PA, it just contains PA. Wouldn't it be correct to say that this implies the impossibility to prove the consistency of PA?

Comment: Suppose we "proved the consistency of PA in a theory T". Then the question immediately arises if T itself is consistent, because if T is not consistent, then each statement (i.e. each formula) $A$ in T is deducible in T together with its negation $\neg A$. In particular, the statement "PA is consistent" is deducible together with the statement "PA is inconsistent". So the question remains open. That is why I think that the second Gödel theorem means impossibility to prove the consistency of PA.

Comment: Your first comment: NO; see [Gentzen's consistency proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof): a theory T "containing" PA can prove PA's consistency. Nevetheless, by G's 2nd Th, T cannot prove T's consistency.

Comment: Second comment: this is the issue ! We may "obviously" prove the consistency of PA using ZF and proving **in** ZF that the "usual" set-theoretic construction of $\mathbb N$ satisfy Peano's axioms (you can find it in many textbooks). **Of course**, the "affordability" of this proof relies on the consistency of ZF. Clearly, ZF is cons iff it has a model: and so on.

Comment: If the "consistency" in the first Gödel theorem is understood as "relative consistency", then this should be pointed out, isn't that?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov It's not about relative consistency, the point is that the theory *in which your argument is carried out* isn't PA itself, so there's no paradox; see my answer for further details.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

Based on the comment thread, I think the underlying question here is: *how is mathematical logic, as a field, "done"?* And this is a special case of asking how *mathematics* is done. While focusing on logic may predispose one towards one method or another, ultimately those same methods make sense for all of mathematics.

***In what follows I'm going to ignore the issue of the consistency of the formal theories we consider; I'll come back to this at the end. Also, the usual caveat: everything I say below is my own opinion and need not reflect the opinions of other mathematicians.***

There are to my mind three basic ways of viewing the activity of mathematics. Many mathematicians, myself included, don't adhere to one particular way all the time, so this is somewhat artificial, but I think it's very useful in understanding mathematics as practiced and will also help address your concerns:

> **Mathematics as informal-but-precise**

At one pole we have mathematics as usually practiced: perhaps surprisingly, it is extremely (from a logical standpoint) *informal*. If you look at an advanced textbook, or a research article, you'll quickly see what I mean: there is almost never any talk of a specific axiom system being used. There are exceptions - sometimes one axiom or another is singled out as being not "intuitively obvious," usually the axiom of choice, and then it is either not used or its use is explicitly remarked - but usually all arguments are via "intuitively obvious" principles, including principles about sets. Incidentally, ZFC and the other set theories emerged mostly as an attempt to *articulate* those principles precisely.

In this context, here's how one mathematician would tell another  mathematician about the completeness theorem: $$\mbox{"If $T$ is a consistent first-order theory, then $T$ has a model. Here's the proof: ..."}$$ Note that the completeness theorem is not qualified by reference to any external axiom system, and the "proof" is an argument in natural language.

This is how mathematics is practiced almost always. But one might reasonably find this unsatisfying; and logicians are, in my experience, somewhat more likely to be uncomfortable with the above picture than mathematicians in general. This takes us to the middle of the road:

> **Mathematics as formalizable arguments**

There is a natural fix for the above approach, which doesn't require us to change our practices too much: we can add a layer of interpretation to the above idea, which fortuitously tends to match working mathematicians' attitudes towards axiom systems in general.

This layer of interpretation is  that it is left to the reader to isolate an appropriate axiom system in which the given informal proof can be formalized and is valid. The reader is free to choose the system in question, so long as it fits those criteria.

How does this work? Let's say I read Wiles' paper proving Fermat's last theorem (FLT). Now, this paper never mentions a specific axiom system; indeed, I believe ([the pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/~lekheng/flt/wiles.pdf) is not searchable unfortunately) that the word "axiom" is never even mentioned. But the paper concludes "FLT is true."

Reading the paper, I want to convince myself that there is a formal theory $T$ such that $T$ proves FLT, by essentially the argument in the paper. Depending on how much I care about parsimoniousness, I might try to make $T$ as weak as possible (and this is an active area of research - Colin McLarty is working on [proving FLT from the smallest set of axioms possible](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsl/1286284558)), but maybe I just want *some* theory that does the job.

It's here that the value of ZFC reveals itself. On the one hand its axioms are extremely well justified from an intuitive standpoint (this is of course opinion, but I believe it is almost universal amongst those interested in formal set theories), especially if we drop the axiom of choice, so a proof from ZFC (or better, ZF) would be taken as a proof, full stop, by the vast majority of the mathematical community. On the other hand it is so powerful that with a bit of experience it's usually easy to convince oneself that a given argument can be translated into it. In particular, even if one doubts ZFC's "acceptability" (whether because one is doubtful that it is consistent, or some other reason), it is easy to convince oneself that the argument given can be converted to a ZFC proof.

*Note that there's a separate issue of **usability**: ZFC is notoriously bad to actually work with - but we're not actually trying to produce a proof here, just convince ourselves that one **exists**, and for that ZFC is extremely satisfactory. I've said more about this [in my answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1845719/28111).*

In this context, here's how one mathematician would tell another mathematician about the completeness theorem: $$\mbox{"Suppose $T$ is a theory that can prove some basic facts about infinite sets like ....}$$ $$\mbox{Then $T$ proves "Every consistent theory has a model."}$$ Often when we're extremely confident about the naturalness of the axioms used, we'll say "Any *reasonable* theory of sets $T$ can prove "every consistent theory has a model," even though this is substantially closer to the previous approach to mathematics.

Of course, given all this there is a serious question of **what constitutes a proof**, even though we have more rigor here than in the previous version. Part of this is the problem of convincing-but-wrong proofs, or proofs which are formalizable in a reasonable axiom system, but need a bit more than ZFC even though that's not apparent. his is a serious and long-running debate within mathematics which I will not attempt to summarize here.

Whatever its flaws, the other pole of mathematics-as-activity certainly avoids this dilemma. Speaking of which, that other pole is:

> **Mathematics as the construction of formal proofs**

Here the only statements we are comfortable with are those of the form

$$(*)\quad\mbox{$\mathfrak{S}$ is a proof of $\varphi$ in $T$,}$$ where $T$ is a first-order theory, $\varphi$ is a sentence in the language of $T$, and $\mathfrak{S}$ is a formal proof of $\varphi$ from the axioms of $T$. $(*)$ is a purely finite statement, and is checkable by a computer, so the philosophical issues around mathematical truth, existence, etc. don't even crop up.

These mathematicians might not be interested in looking at informal proofs except as recipes for producing formal proofs. For such a mathematician, we never assert what the other two types of mathematician might call "mathematical facts" - we assert claims of *provability from specific systems*, and back those claims up with actual, ideally computer-checkable formal proofs.

In this context, here's how one mathematician would tell another mathematician about the completeness theorem: $$\mbox{Here's a proof of "every consistent theory $T$ has a model" in ZFC.}$$ Another thing they might say is $$\mbox{Here's a proof of "every consistent theory $T$ has a model" in WKL$_0$.}$$ And so on. I believe statements like this are the ones you'll be most comfortable with, at least at first.

The only step I've left out is the work of expressing a sentence like "every consistent theory $T$ has a model" in the given formal language, and in fact the totally formal mathematician would view this as ultimately unperformable: at best, the sentence $\varphi$ is a formal sentence which *corresponds in some way* to the natural language sentence "every consistent theory $T$ has a model."

Note that this constitutes a meaningful step away from the idea of proof as illuminating - a formal proof, even after being computer-checked, need not give the reader any understanding of *why* the result is true in the given axiom system. For this reason formal proofs (think the four-color theorem, Kepler's conjecture, etc.) are often viewed as unsatisfactory by the mathematical community, even though they are far more rigorous.

$$$$

Okay, now let's talk about the elephant in the room:

> **Consistency**

Let's go bottom-to-top.

The lovely thing about formal proofs is that *consistency plays no role in the facts we assert*! When I exhibit a formal proof of $\varphi$ in $T$, I don't need to qualify it with "if $T$ is consistent;" regardless of $T$'s consistency, I know now that $T$ proves $\varphi$. If $T$ is inconsistent this fact is *trivial*, but it doesn't make it *false*. So while I'm more interested in statements of the form "$\mathfrak{S}$ is a proof of $\varphi$ from $T$" for consistent $T$, nothing breaks down if a theory I thought was consistent turns out to be inconsistent.

For the second approach things are more nuanced. Let's say we find out that ZFC is inconsistent. Then we now know that every time we accepted a proof by saying, "It goes through in ZFC" (or stronger), we made a terrible mistake; and now we need to go back to those results and reexamine them to see if we can convince ourselves that they can be proved in a theory $T$ which we *still* think is consistent. It is generally agreed that the answer would almost always be yes.

For the first approach the game fundamentally changes. The consistency of formal theories is a non-issue, **since we're not working inside one in the first place**; so the relevant consistency issue is whether we can prove a contradiction from "intuitively obvious" first principles.

Now there's an extremely interesting story here: how this issue cropped up in the past, and how it was handled. I can think of a few instances that might or might not count. *Note that I'm not a historian, so I'm woefully unqualified to comment here, but that's never stopped me before!*

- The earlies candidate is **irrational numbers**. [There's a famous story, whose veracity I'm not prepared to argue for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippasus#Irrational_numbers) of the reaction to the discovery of irrational numbers - according to the story (whose veracity I'm not prepared to argue for), they contradicted an existing philosophy/theology of numbers. However, this tended to not be a major problem for those outside this philosophy, as far as I know.
- A wonderfully explicit example is provided by **Non-Euclidean geometries**. This is because it became a huge philosophical focus point: Kant argued, and many mathematicians and philosophers agreed, that non-Euclidean geometries would contradict our fundamental intuitions about reality to the point of arguably being *epistemologically impossible*. (OK, what Kant said was more nuanced, I'm not a philosopher, sue me.) *Out of fairness I should say that some people have argued that the discovery of non-Euclidean geometries is actually not damaging to Kant's philosophy; I disagree, but it should be mentioned.*
- Yet another instance of this is the gradual acceptance of **complex numbers**, starting with their appearance in intermediate steps of the solution to a cubic equation and continuing on through their acceptance as consistent objects to the general belief in their existence on par with other mathematical entities (not universally accepted of course).
- **The definition of "function"** evolved to allow such beasts as the Dirichlet function, which were originally not considered functions in the first place. This isn't really a contradiction of *axioms*, but should count partly on this list since it represents a clashing of fundamental intuitions (about what a function should be), and also because historically it helped setthe stage for ...
- ... **The axiom of choice**, which provides maybe the most on-point example, Kant notwithstanding. You may have heard the joke "The axiom of choice is obviously true, the well-ordering principle is obviously false, and who can tell about Zorn's lemma."

What's fascinating about this is that in each case, mathematical practice stabilized (quickly or eventually). In particular, in the case of the axiom of choice, the axiom was eventually largely accepted by the mathematical community, the intuitions for it trumping the intuitions against it (and this battle between intuitions being affected by the axiom's implicit role in existing mathematics). This was the closest to a genuine "rift," I think - there are many more mathematicians seriously skeptical of the axiom of choice than of (as far as I know) complex numbers, nowhere-continuous functions, etc. - but even here a stable state emerged: unless otherwise mentioned, the axiom of choice is taken as accepted (or is irrelevant) in mathematical proofs. At the same time, it is perfectly respectable to study mathematics without choice, or assuming an actual denial of choice, so long as it is explicitly done. So even though no intuition in particular "won out" totally, our understanding of those fundamental intuitions emerged to the point that they no longer pose a problem to each other, and the practice that emerged ultimately makes perfect sense once we view mathematics as a *social activity*.

**So what's the completeness theorem?**

- Every consistent theory has a model.
- Any "reasonable" set theory proves that every consistent theory has a model.
- Check it out, here's a computer-verified proof of the sentence "every consistent theory has a model" in ZFC: [exercise for the reader]. And here's a computer-verified proof of the sentence "every consistent theory has a model" in WKL$_0$: [another exercise for the reader]. Neat, huh?

Regardless of which one you pick, **the argument you've outlined in your question breaks down immediately**, and so there's no problem.

$$$$

$$$$

$$$$

$$$$

---

**Original answer:**

As almost always is the case with such questions, the issue is: *where* are you proving the assertions you make?

Let's work with ZFC instead of PA, for simplicty (I'll explain why below). Then your argument looks like:

- If ZFC has a model, then ZFC is consistent. *(You only need this direction, the **soundness** theorem, rather than the whole completeness theorem.)*
- ZFC has a model. *(This is less intuitively obvious than "PA has a model," but bear with me for now.)*
- Therefore ZFC is consistent.
- But now we've proved the consistency of ZFC, contradicting Incompleteness.

Now, ZFC certainly proves the soundness theorem. The issue here is the second bullet point: ZFC cannot prove that ZFC has a model! So the theory in which we've proved "ZFC is consistent" is a theory stronger than ZFC itself, and so there's no problem here.

So the issue is: the crucial step in your argument is arguing that the theory in question has a model in the first place, and this - no matter how obvious to you - cannot be done in that theory itself.

---

Now why did I work in ZFC rather than PA?

Well, it turns out that PA is absolutely terrible at talking about models! A model is a set together with some relations and functions. Well, by the Ackermann interpretation (see Section 5 of [this article](http://www.dwolf.eu/uploads/2/7/1/3/27138059/mmath_project_dwood.pdf)), PA can talk about finite sets; but not infinite sets! This means, among other things:

- PA proves that PA has no model, since PA proves that any model of PA would have to be infinite.
- In fact, PA *disproves* the completeness theorem - PA proves that Robinson's theory $Q$ is consistent, but also proves that any model of $Q$ must be infinite, hence proves that $Q$ has no models.

So PA is a terrible theory to work in if we're doing model theory.

Instead, we need to work in a theory capable of handling infinite sets. This actually isn't much of a requirement: above I worked with the ultra-strong theory ZFC, since it's well-known, but there are satisfactory theories which are consistent relative to PA - for example, the theory WKL$_0$ proves the completeness theorem, and PA proves that WKL$_0$ is consistent! So externally we can say, "**Obviously** WKL$_0$ has a model," but that assertion can't be made in WKL$_0$ itself.

*Incidentally, there are ways to do model theory inside PA - see e.g. the "arithmetized completeness theorem" - but they're much more involved, and I'm ignoring them here for simplicity.*

Comment: Noah, why do you say that this is not about relative consistency? From your answer I would deduce that the problem lies in the inaccuracy of the formulation of the Gödel completeness theorem. It must be specified as follows and the problem will disappear: "If a theory $T$ is consistent and a theory $S$ has a model in $T$, then $S$ is consistent as well". Is that correct?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov No, that's not correct. I mean, that is a correct statement (although "$S$ has a model in $T$" should be replaced by "$T$ proves that $S$ has a model," and technically you need a small assumption on $T$ for it to be true - you need $T$ to prove soundness), but the completeness theorem is completely accurate: the statement "$S$ is consistent iff $S$ has a model" is provable in ZFC. And the "in ZFC" shouldn't give you pause - *any* theorem is proved *in some theory*. If you like you can prove the completeness theorem in much less than ZFC; WKL$_0$ is already enough.

Comment: The problem will disappear as soon as you realize that no (reasonable) theory proves that it has a model. That's it - that resolves the entire issue. Even if such a theory proves the completeness theorem, it won't be able to *apply* it in the way that you've indicated.

Comment: "no (reasonable) theory proves that it has a model" - do you mean here that "there is no theory $T$ that has a model in $T$"?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov What does "has a model in $T$" mean? The only thing that can mean is "$T$-provably has a model" - a theory isn't a structure in which models actually exist, it's a set of sentences saying certain things. And no, you need the adjective "reasonable" - firstly, there are very strange weak theories, and a too-weak theory might not be able to conclude that a theory is consistent by virtue of it having a model (as strange as that sounds); and secondly, in order for "$T$ has a model" to even be expressible $T$ needs to be appropriately definable.

Comment: (Similar "reasonability" assumptions, by the way, are needed in Goedel's incompleteness theorem: e.g. Dan Willard has studied [consistent theories which prove their own consistency](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0022580), and do so by virtue of not being strong enough for the Goedel analysis to apply.) So, to sum up: I mean exactly what I wrote.

Comment: I thought "$S$ has a model in $T$" means that there is an interpretation of $S$ in $T$ in the sense of J.Shoenfiled. Or maybe some specification of this notion.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov If that's what you mean by that, you need to say that - usually the phrase "$S$ has a model in $T$" would be interpreted as "$T$ proves $S$ has a model." Regardless, I meant what I wrote above, and the completeness theorem is perfectly accurate; do you understand why?

Comment: Noah, I'll try to translate into your language. I will use the expression "$T$ proves that $S$ has a model", if $S$ has an interpretation in $T$ in the sense of Shoenfield (Section 4.7). I do understand that there is no "reasonable" theory $T$ such that $T$ proves that $T$ has a model. Is that what you are worrying about?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov "I will say that "$T$ proves that $S$ has a model", if $S$ has an interpretation in $T$ in the sense of Shoenfield (Section 4.7)." Wait, what? **No** - the phrase "$T$ proves that $S$ has a model" means a specific thing, having nothing to do with interpretations - it means that $T$ proves the sentence, "$S$ has a model," when appropriately formalized in the language of $T$. What *exactly* do you want to say here?

Comment: Let me ask: do you accept the proof - in "unformalized" mathematics (so, the same context that we usually prove things like "Every ring that's a field has a nontrivial proper ideal") - that a theory is consistent iff it has a model? (That is, the completeness theorem.) If not, why not?

Comment: I thought models are special cases of interpretations, it's not true? Noah, I need a textbook to understand your terminology. What you explain here, where is it written?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what "unformalized mathematics" is. I thought each proof can be formalized. What is meant by "unformalized mathematics"?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov There are two different meanings for the word "interpretation" - as used to describe part of a model (a model is a set + an interpretation), or as used to say things like "$\mathcal{A}$ is interpretable in $\mathcal{B}$." I don't have Shoenfield on hand so I don't know what he says in section 4.7; but the word "model" is used unambiguously, so I'm going with that. (I'm not sure what you mean by "special case.") I don't know what you're looking for in terms of a text - this is how the completeness theorem is stated in every text I've read. (cont'd)

Comment: Re: unformalized math, I just mean math as normally practiced. Most math papers - indeed, almost every math paper outside of logic - doesn't pay particular attention to any axiom system, and presents proofs in natural language, rather than formal logic.

Comment: I used to think that everything written in this informal style can be translated into the language of Gentzen sequent calculus. So I don't feel the difference, actually.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Sure, it can be - but the point is that it *currently isn't*. And before diving into a formal proof, it's good to have anintuition for what's going on, and that's best supplied by an *informal* proof (have you ever really understood a proof by *first* seeing it presented entirely formally?). So I'm asking, basically: do you understand intuitively what's going on with the proof of the completeness theorem? I'm separating this from the formal proof in some theory because understanding why e.g. ZFC proves the theorem isn't the same as understanding why the theorem "should" be true.

Comment: I can send you the book by Shoenfield by email. From what he writes it follows that "models" are some special cases of the notion of "interpretation of a theory $S$ into a theory $T$". The specifications are that $T$ must be some kind of set theory, and also there are some minor corrections.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov OK, can we ignore Shoenfield for now? I'm really not interested in talking about interpretability here, that's completely unnecessary for talking about the completeness theorem. (That said, based on your comment I can decode what he means, and he's right - I just don't see the value of introducing interpretability here, when we just care about models.) The relevant question which I need an answer to before I can give more help here (because I don't understand the remaining issue(s) right now) is: **is there a part of the proof of the completeness theorem that you don't accept?**

Comment: Noah this is an extremely interesting conversation, but I am afraid that you will be disappointed very quickly by my stupidity. So my apologies from the very beginning. :) As to the proof of the completeness theorem what I don't understand there is the idea of using the notion of set without specifying which axiomatic set theory we use here. That is why every time when I am reading texts on logic, I am trying to translate them into the language that I understand by replacing proper axiomatic set theories into  the proper places. Whout this I don't understand what is written there.

Comment: I asked a special question about this some time ago at mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251099/are-there-textbooks-on-logic-where-the-references-to-set-theory-appear-only-afte

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov "I am afraid that you will be disappointed very quickly by my stupidity" - nothing of the sort, and I hope I haven't come across this way! You're asking very good questions, I'm just having trouble teasing apart exactly what they mean. "what I don't understand there is the idea of using the notion of set without specifying which axiomatic set theory we use here" Great - so it sounds like you do understand the idea of the proof, and what's getting you tripped up is its formalization? If so, the point is: any "reasonable" set theory proves the completeness theorem.

Comment: "any "reasonable" set theory proves the completeness theorem" -- I would add "under an assumption that this set theory is itself consistent".

Comment: I think a good way to see this is actually to work with something much weaker than ZFC - Simpson's book ["Subsystems of second-order arithmetic"](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/sosoa/chapter1.pdf) does (if I recall correctly) a good job of outlining a formal proof of the completeness theorem from the very weak theory WKL$_0$. Very interestingly, he shows that in fact the completeness theorem is **equivalent** to WKL$_0$ in a precise sense (if you're interested in such things, this is called "reverse mathematics" and is the real topic of Simpson's book).

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov "I would add "under an assumption that this set theory is itself consistent"." Not necessary - an inconsistent theory proves everything! :P More seriously, I consider inconsistenct to not be "reasonable."

Comment: I don't understand, however. If the enveloping theory is inconsistent then one can prove that the inner theory is inconsistent as well. So to avoid this effect we should make sure that the enveloping theory is consistent. Noah, the way how you, logicians, explain your science is awful.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov "If the enveloping theory is inconsistent then one can prove that the inner theory is inconsistent as well." No, if the enveloping theory is inconsistent then **that theory** proves that the inner theory is also inconsistent; but that need not mean that the inner theory is, actually, inconsistent! Inconsistent theories prove false things - e.g. if $T$ is inconsistent, then $T$ proves "$PA$ is inconsistent," but you don't believe $PA$ is inconsistent do you?

Comment: Noah, I did not mean you, excuse me. I meant textbooks.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Alright, forget for now concerns about the ambient theory: look at Simpson's proof of the completeness theorem inside WKL$_0$. (This is actually slightly less general than the full completeness theorem, since it only treats countable languages - to do uncountable languages justice, we need a genuine set theory, and also some amount of the axiom of choice - but since the theories we care about are in countable languages, that's not a huge point here.) I think you'll find it very helpful. Alternatively, what exactly goes wrong when you try to translate the standard proof into ZFC?

Comment: I will look at Simpson's proof. Where is it written? As to translating into ZFC, the problem for me is that I find doubtful the conclusion that PA is consistent from the fact that PA has a model in ZFC. I don't understand something important.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Oh, I think I see the issue: you're saying that you don't feel comfortable concluding "PA is consistent" from the fact "ZFC proves that PA has a model," given that you would need the further assumption that ZFC is consistent? If so, this is correct. However, again we have to specify what we're proving **where**: ZFC proves that PA has a model, and ZFC proves the soundness theorem, so **ZFC proves** that PA is consistent. This is a different thing than externally-to-ZFC concluding that PA is consistent. Whenever you're doing formal mathematics, you work inside some formal theory;

Comment: and everything you prove is proved within that theory. So when we assert e.g. "PA is consistent because PA has a model," a formalization of that statement would be "ZFC proves that PA is consistent because ZFC proves that PA has a model" (note that this is true regardless of whether ZFC is consistent, since if ZFC is inconsistent it proves that PA is consistent since it proves everything!).

Comment: Yes, that is a problem for me: "you're saying that you don't feel comfortable concluding "PA is consistent" from the fact "ZFC proves that PA has a model," given that you would need the further assumption that ZFC is consistent?" Noah, I think I must read Simpson, maybe after that I will understand. Now it is late here in Moscow, I will write about the results maybe tomorrow, or in several days. Thank you for your patience. :)

Comment: Noah, it seems to me, I understood the architecture of your science, it is the following: 1) you introduce the extensions by definition (Kunen, II.15), 2) you define interpretations of a theory in another theory (in the spirit of Shoenfield, 4.7), 3) you prove Gödel's incompleteness theorems for theories $T$, in which extensions PA can be interpreted, 4) you choose an axiomatic set theory (e.g. ZFC) and declare your "credo": "we believe that this theory is consistent", and 5) only after that you define models as  interpretations in extensions of ZFC, and prove the rest.

Comment: If you arrange your explanations like this, all the difficulties disappear.

Comment: I asked a new question that clarifies my point: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318295/versions-of-g%C3%B6dels-incompleteness-theorems

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I have some issues with the outline you've given of what "my science" is doing. I've edited my question substantially: I've added a brief essay on mathematical practice and formal proof. Hopefully this clarifies things. (Incidentally, I *really really* suggest you stop thinking of models in terms of interpretations of one theory in another, and more in terms of sets with structure - in particular, if you think this way the confusion Asaf pointed out in your new question is clearly revealed.)

Comment: Noah, I am sorry, but I don't agree with this: "Regardless of which one you pick, the argument you've outlined in your question breaks down immediately, and so there's no problem." I believe that **each explanation must be simple and clear**. It is always possible to rearrange your reasonons in such a way that the doubtful places disappear. A mathematical theory has no right to be so provoking and so neglecting to the common rules. E.g., this - "stop thinking... of interpretations..." - contradicts to the tradition: when people see a similarity they always think about possible connections.

Comment: Another example is what I mentioned before, the neglection of the idea of linearity in exposition: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251099/are-there-textbooks-on-logic-where-the-references-to-set-theory-appear-only-afte You pay attention to the psychological factors in your post. For me as an outlooker all this picture looks like an attempt to shade the fact of **taking to trust the consistency of axiomatic set theories**. You seem to hesitate this (since this does not look as an appropriate scientific trick) and that is the explanation of the strange complexity of your explanations.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov "E.g., this - "stop thinking... of interpretations..." - contradicts to the tradition: when people see a similarity they always think about possible connections." Too bad; *some connections are unhelpful for building intuition,* and this is true in every field of study. Your insistence on simplicity can quickly turn into a resistance to criticism of intuition, and I believe it has in this context. Regardless, your argument in the OP is still completely wrong: it hinges on the claim that the theory in question proves that it has a model, which is simply not true. (cont'd)

Comment: I really don't know what you want at this point. I've given you the most unobjectionable version of the completeness theorem possible - "ZFC proves the sentence "every consistent theory has a model"" - one which is absolutely precise, makes no reference to mathematical truth, and can be verified by a computer, and this doesn't seem to be enough; why? And you **still** haven't addressed the problem with the argument in your question. At this point I'm hesitant to respond further, since I really don't understand what it is that *you* don't understand now.

Comment: As to @AsafKaragila , I would suggest him to be clearer. Math.stackexchange is not a closed club, people are not obliged to be specialist in what he is a specialist, and catch hints.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Asaf has been perfectly clear. If you don't understand what he's saying, state a *specific confusion*; what point don't you get?

Comment: One last attempt: do you understand the statement, "ZFC proves 'every consistent theory has a model'"? Do you believe that that statement ("ZFC proves 'every consistent theory has a model'") is true? Until you answer these questions, there's nothing I can do to help, since the exact point of confusion will remain unclear to me.

Comment: I don't understand details in Asaf's comment. This happens to people who are not specialists in your area. You can make a comment there if you understand him.

Comment: Yes, I have no objections against this: "ZFC proves 'every consistent theory has a model'". Noah, moderators will punish us for this long discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60284/discussion-between-noah-schweber-and-sergei-akbarov).